# Rails jquery dropdown menu for multiple menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm very new to jquery, quite dumb when it comes to it (and javascript). After many hours of searches, I came upon a very simple way to create a dropdown menu. It works find, except it will only work for one parent item, I need to be able to create more than one dropdown menu with it so I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to edit the code to make it work.

Here's what I have:

The jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dropdown').hover(         
        function () {
            //change the background of parent menu              
            $('#dropdown li a.parent').addClass('hover');

            //display the submenu
            $('#dropdown ul.children').show();                 
        },

        function () { 
            //change the background of parent menu
            $('#dropdown li a.parent').removeClass('hover');            

            //display the submenu
            $('#dropdown ul.children').hide();                 
        }         
    );         
});
```

Menus markup:

```
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#" class="parent">Searches</a> 
        <ul class="children">
            <li><%= link_to 'search1', path1 %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'search2', path2 %></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" class="parent">UPCs</a> 
        <ul class="children">
            <li><%= link_to 'search1', path1 %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'search2', path2 %></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul> <!-- id dropdown end tag -->
```

Right now, hovering over either element (Searches or UPCs) produces one menu of course with all children. The idea is to be able to produce the children under each parent.

Thanks.

PS
If anyone has a *simple*, better way to do it (maybe a plugin that really works) I'd be delighted to hear about it as well. I really need something simple, I don't want to have to learn javascript for this (that's one of the reasons why I got away from PHP and into Rails in the first place).

I realise that a simple way would be to make 2 (or more) different `<ul id="dropdown2">`, etc lists, but I have no idea how to pass the right one to the jquery function or what to do about the CSS which is only written for `#dropdown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.dropdown li').hover(         
        function () {             
            $(this).addClass('hover');
            $('> ul.children', $(this)).show();                 
        },

        function () { 
            $(this).removeClass('hover');            
            $('> ul.children', $(this)).hide();                
        }         
    );         
});
```

It will works for each element with class `dropdown`.

But you could do this using `CSS` without `jQuery`:

```
.dropdown li ul {
    display: none;
}
.dropdown li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

But it will not works in old version of Internet Explorer

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work at all on my page, I don't get any menus whatsoever, not even the first one. Is there anything else I need to change? I substituted all the code in the .js document with what you typed in the answer.

Comment: Are you changed `<ul id="dropdown">` to `<ul class="dropdown">` (or `<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown">`?

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that change from ID to class. Now it works, but the problem I have is that the child menu always appears below the first menu and I need it to appear below each menu. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just add class `dropdown` for each menu (`<ul class="dropdown" id="dd1">`, `<ul class="dropdown" id="dd2">` etc)